# Trained data file of IAM Handwriting Database for Tesseract

Tags: tesseract, handwriting-recognition

Can someone please give me the trained data file of IAM handwriting database for use with tesseract.I need the .traineddata file please.

Comment: This is not a technical question. It is rather "can someone do work instead of me, please". It's not worth being on stackoverflow. Downvoted. Please, add what you tried to do on your way to resolve problem by yourself, then explain your issues and difficulties. Then I recall my downvote.